# jooq, fill field value on insert, similar to record_timestamp

Tags: java, sql, jooq

Each table in my database have these fixed columns:

- record_version
- record_timestamp
- create_time

Thanks to jooq [feature](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.0/manual-single-page/#codegen-tables) record_version and record_timestamp are automatically handled.

Is it possible to **centralize and automate the maintenance** of create_time ?
Internally jooq is already managing the first two special fields.

Can I put a handler somewhere to fill the create_time value?
Doing so, I could remove some boilerplate code to initialize this field.

I have another field on each table: update_by_account; anyway If I'm able to manage the previous mentioned field (create_time) I think I'll handle this field too.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Future jOOQ versions:

What you're looking for is the [Listener API feature](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2010) for `Record` and `UpdatableRecord`. It has not yet been implemented as of jOOQ 3.0

In the future, this feature will allow to inject some behaviour to jOOQ's records, when they are stored, inserted, updated, deleted, etc. This would include what you are requesting as well as what jOOQ is currently doing with its

- `record_version`
- `record_timestamp`

columns used for optimistic locking.

#### A solution for jOOQ 2.x or 3.0:

What you can do right now is implement an [`ExecuteListener`](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.0/manual/sql-execution/execute-listeners/) and let it "detect" if it should become active and override a bind value for `create_time`. This will probably have to resort to parsing or at least regex-matching your SQL statement.

#### A SQL-only solution:

However, the best option for `create_time`, in my opinion, is to write a trigger for every one of your tables (Oracle syntax):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER my_trigger
BEFORE INSERT
ON my_table
REFERENCING NEW AS new
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    :new.create_time = SYSDATE;
END t_triggers_trigger;
```

This will guarantee that the value is available no matter how you access your database...

Comment: Thanks Lukas. Is there a release plan for jOOQ 3.1?

Comment: Nope, not yet. Anyway, I'm not sure if this particular feature will really make it into jOOQ 3.1...